# Fool-proof algorithm for uniformly distributing points on a sphere's surface?

Tags: python, numpy, computational-geometry

I've been trying to generate points on the surface of a sphere of radius "inner_radius", such that they're uniformly spread out. The algorithm works as expected for a radius of 1, but generates lesser than expected points for greater radii.
I have looked through similar questions on here, but they seem to be for generating points throughout the volume and not just on the surface of the sphere.

```
import numpy as np
PI=np.pi

def spherical_to_cartesian(pol_ang,azim_ang,radius): #This function converts given spherical coordinates (theta, phi and radius) to cartesian coordinates.
    return np.array((radius*np.sin(pol_ang) * np.cos(azim_ang),
                        radius*np.sin(pol_ang) * np.sin(azim_ang),
                        radius*np.cos(pol_ang))
                        )

def get_electron_coordinates_list(inner_radius,electron_count):
    #Algorithm used was mostly  taken from https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/sphere_equi.pdf . Explanations in code added by me.
    electron_coordinate_list=[]
    inner_area=4*(PI*inner_radius**2)
    area_per_electron=inner_area/electron_count
    pseudo_length_per_electron=np.sqrt(area_per_electron) #This is the side length of a square where the area of it is the area per electron on the sphere.
    #Now, we need to get a value of angular space, such that angular space between electrons on latitude and longitude per electron is equal
    #As a first step to obtaining this, we must make another value holding a whole number approximation of the ratio between PI and the pseudo_length. This will give the number of 
    #possible latitudes.

    possible_count_of_lats=np.round(PI/pseudo_length_per_electron)

    approx_length_per_electron_lat=PI/possible_count_of_lats #This is the length between electrons on a latitude
    approx_length_per_electron_long=area_per_electron/approx_length_per_electron_lat #This is the length between electrons on a longitude

    for electron_num_lat in range(int(possible_count_of_lats.item())): #The int(somenumpyvalue.item()) is used because Python cannot iterate over a numpy integer and it must be converted to normal int.
        pol_ang=PI*(electron_num_lat+0.5)/possible_count_of_lats #The original algorithm recommended pol_ang=PI*(electron_num_lat+0.5)/possible_count_of_lats. The 0.5 appears to be added in order to get a larger number of coordinates.
        #not sure if removing the 0.5 affects results. It didnt do so drastically, so what gives? Anyway, this gets the polar angle as PI*(latitudenumber)/totalnumberoflatitudes.

        possible_count_of_longs=np.round(2*PI*np.sin(pol_ang)/approx_length_per_electron_long)

        for electron_num_long in range(int(possible_count_of_longs.item())):

            azim_ang=(2*PI)*(electron_num_long)/possible_count_of_longs #This gets the azimuthal angle as 2PI*longitudenumber/totalnumberoflongitudes

            electron_coordinate=spherical_to_cartesian(pol_ang, azim_ang,inner_radius) #Converts the recieved spherical coordinates to cartesian so Manim can easily handle them.
            electron_coordinate_list.append(electron_coordinate) #Add this coordinate to the electron_coordinate_list

            print("Got coordinates: ",electron_coordinate) #Print the coordinate recieved.
    print(len(electron_coordinate_list)," points generated.") #Print the amount of electrons will exist. Comment these two lines out if you don't need the data.

    return electron_coordinate_list 
get_electron_coordinates_list(1,100)
get_electron_coordinates_list(2,100)
```

Spherical_to_Cartesian() does nothing other than convert the spherical points to Cartesian.

For 100 points and radius 1, it generates 99 points.
But, only 26 points are made if the radius is 2 and 100 points are requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can generate points uniformly in the sphere's volume, then to get a uniform distribution on the sphere's surface, you can simply normalize the vectors so their radius equals the sphere's radius.

Alternatively, you can use the fact that independent identically-distributed normal distributions are [rotationally-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem). If you sample from 3 normal distributions with mean 1 and standard deviation 0, and then likewise normalize the vector, it will be uniform on the sphere's surface. Here's an example:

```py
import random

def sample_sphere_surface(radius=1):
    x, y, z = (random.normalvariate(0, 1) for i in range(3))
    scalar = radius / (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) ** 0.5
    return (x * scalar, y * scalar, z * scalar)
```

To be *absolutely* foolproof, we can handle the astronomically unlikely case of a division-by-zero error when `x`, `y` and `z` all happen to be zero:

```py
def sample_sphere_surface(radius=1):
    while True:
        try:
            x, y, z = (random.normalvariate(0, 1) for i in range(3))
            scalar = radius / (x**2 + y**2 + z**2) ** 0.5
            return (x * scalar, y * scalar, z * scalar)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The element of area is, in polar coordinates, `sinΘ dΘ dφ`. Hence the azimuth angle can be uniformly distributed, while the inclination must be redistributed. Using the inverse transform sampling trick, `Θ=arccos(u)` where `u` is drawn uniformly will do.

Hence in Cartesian coordinates, `(√(1-u²) cos v, √(1-u²) sin v, u)` where `u` is drawn from `[-1,1)` and `v` from `[0,2π)`.